# Bootstrap modal behaviour

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

My site is normally like this[image]

But when a modal is displayed by clicking a button this happens, observe area below modal [image]

Is there a way to fix this behaviour? (**the navbar elements are displaced when modal is shown and return to normal when modal hides**)

The code is directly from example here http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What behavior do you want to fix specifically?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: u want to access ur Menu Bar though ur Modal Window is on ur Screen?

Comment: Could it be due to the scrollbar showing in the browser window when the modal opens? I'd take a look at that first. We need some more information to help you like html / css source if possible...